# How to jQuery.loadTemplate into new element without providing any existing container?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#template-container").loadTemplate($("#template"),
{
    author: 'Joe Bloggs',
    date: '25th May 2013',
    authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
    post: 'This is the contents of my post'
});
```

In this sample is needed existing #template-container element, how to directly create new element on the fly and fill it from template?

Comment: Could you elaborate your needs a little more? what do you meant by `new element`? from where the new element coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use same as with container. For example:

You  can  use to load the template into newly created div element and append it to some other element.

```
$('<div/>').loadTemplate($("#template"), {
    author: 'Joe Bloggs',
    date: '25th May 2013',
    authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
    post: 'This is the contents of my post'
}).appendTo("#someohter_element");
```

or if you have reference to any dynamically created element like

```
var el = $('<div/>');
```

then you can also call

```
el.loadTemplate($("#template"), {
  author: 'Joe Bloggs',
  date: '25th May 2013',
  authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
  post: 'This is the contents of my post'
});
```

### **Edited**

I'm not sure what you are want to do!!! I could not imagine any other things you may want to do with loading template other then the follows:

1. You may want to show the content in your Page, that case you can just use your element as your container like your code
2. You may not want to show the content in your page, that case you can use my 2nd code snippet.

Anyway, I am out of guessing power!! You can define the following function, and use it to get the content, and do whatever you want with it:

```
 function loadTemplate(template, data, options){
        return $('<div/>').loadTemplate(template, data, options).html();
 }
```

Then use it like:

```
var markup = loadTemplate("#template",
        {
            author: 'Joe Bloggs',
            date: '25th May 2013',
            authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
            post: 'This is the contents of my post'
        });
```

The `markup` variable will contain the html after rendering the template

Happy coding!

Comment: There must be always some container for loading? In your case $('<div/>')
I need to load template also with container element.

Comment: Now I'm confused about your need!!! Can u please clarify what is your requirement. $('<div/>') is an arbitrary dynamic element, it can be any dynamic element. It is not an element on DOM.

Comment: I need to load template without any dynamic element or container

Comment: $('<div/>').loadTemplate() is exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to append data on the container, you can use the `{append: true}` option, for example:

`$("#template-container").loadTemplate($("#template"),
{
    author: 'Joe Bloggs',
    date: '25th May 2013',
    authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
    post: 'This is the contents of my post'
}, {
    append: true
});`